# Android external online database

Tags: php, android, mysql

i have an online database in phpMyAdmin. At this time I can query him and I can get the result in a TextView but i want to get the value of each cell, how do I?

This is an example

```
[{"Monday":"","Tuesday":"","Wednesday":"","Thursday":"","Friday":"","Saturday":"","Sunday":"","id":"","info":""},...]
```

I would like to get the value of Monday for example.

Thanks

code sendQuery.java:

```
 public class sendQuery {
/////////// Public method to send Query ///////////
public static String send(String query) {
    String result = "0";
    InputStream is = null;
    String weekDayVal;
    //the query to send
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> querySend = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    querySend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("querySend",query));

    //http post
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://locali.altervista.org/php/locali.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(querySend));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
        try{
            JSONArray weekDetails = new JSONArray ( result); // Your response string
            for(int index=0;index < weekDetails.length();index++)
            {
            JSONObject tempWeekDetail = weekDetails.getJSONObject(index);
            weekDayVal = tempWeekDetail.getString("Monday");// Value for Monday
            //added this Log which you can view from LogCat. also changed above variable name
            Log.i("Resp Value"," Moday Value"+weekDayVal);
            }
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
            //catch exception here
            }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result: "+e.toString());
    }

    Log.i("SendQUERY", result);
    return result;
}
```

}

main.java:

```
 public class main extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView resLayout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.res);


    String res = sendQuery.send("SELECT * FROM contatti");

    resLayout.append(res);


}
}
```

Comment: post some code you tried with ....

Comment: Try using a JSON library like Gson https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ . It is an easy way to transform json txt to a Java class in android, and then get values easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following code.

```
/*String res = "[{\"Monday\":\"Work\",\"Tuesday\":\"\",\"Wednesday\":\"\",\"Thursday\":\"\",\"Friday\":\"\",\"Saturday\":\"\",\"Sunday\":\"\",\"id\":\"\",\"info\":\"\"}]";//you have to escape double quotes*/

try{
JSONArray weekDetails = new JSONArray ( result); // Your response string
for(int index=0;index < weekDetails.length();index++)
{
JSONObject tempWeekDetail = weekDetails.getJSONObject(index);
String weekDayVal = tempWeekDetail.getString("Monday");// Value for Monday
//added this Log which you can view from LogCat. also changed above variable name
Log.i("Resp Value"," Moday Value"+weekDayVal);
}
}catch(Exception e)
{
//catch exception here
}
```

Comment: put above code where you are getting json response (Which is the string you have provided) as a result and you want to get the value for 'Monday'.

Comment: after result=sb.toString(); ?

Comment: yes no problem. Do write Toast so that you will know if you are getting proper result.

Comment: Forgive me but I do not understand how to do

Comment: i have added log check it out. you cant view logs from LogCat.

Comment: I have updated code.Just put above code after _result=sb.toString();_

Comment: to see the value as I do?

Comment: have you put above code after result=sb.toString(); in send() function. Then check LogCat you will see the value for Monday.

Comment: I modified the code, tell me if it's okay. but in this way the logcat is empty

Comment: but there isn't also "Resp Value"

Comment: change your logcat to info.

Comment: I do not see anything the same

Comment: could you please paste your log cat and your response

Comment: ok now it works but if I had more than one row in the database as I do?

Comment: so it is working now ... you can accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

try to work with JSON, you can easily parse it and extract needed data